# Tracking down "Duplicate Declaration in current scope"

Tags: vba

I understand why I'm getting the error - but because I'm using lots of class modules and handling user input in the click event of a button, I have no idea how to start looking for this problem without working procedurally through it all.

Is this the only option or is there some better way of coding and debugging VBA code?

Comment: Normally you'd need to step through the code. Another way is when you get a run-time error to click the Debug button and this will take you to the line throwing the error. From there you can trace your steps backwards by navigating through the Call Stack. But in your case there is nothing to execute: the project doesn't compile, so the only thing you can do is to find duplicate variable (or constants, or function names) within the function(s) scope, module scope, or public: Try this in VBA editor: Menu Debug -> Compile project. This should highlight the first duplicate it finds

Answer (score 0):

There might be a VBA specific trick that I don't know of, but here is a more generic and less fancy approach. I'm not giving a full solution because you could use a lot of different tools to do the same thing, depending on platform, preference, etc. it should give you an idea of how you could approach the problem, though.

1. Using a multi-file regex tool like linux's grep, my preference of [Ack](http://beyondgrep.com) (Windows and UNIX), or whatever you're comfortable with to extract a list of all `Dim` statements
2. Use command line tools or excel to get a count of each unique `Dim` statement
3. For each of the identifiers that are `Dim`'d more than once, use your IDE's search function to check if they're `Dim`'d twice in the same scope